# In python two variable a=10,b=10 then there id(a),id(b) is same but for a=5234,b=5234 id(a),id(b) is different sometimes it gives diffrenet location

Tags: python, memory

In python two variable `a=10,b=10` then there `id(a),id(b)` is same but for `a=5234,b=5234 id(a),id(b)` is different
example:

```
a=12
b=12
print(id(a),id(b))
c=51324344343
d=51324344343
print(id(c),id(d))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885782/why-are-larger-int-numbers-returning-different-and-sometimes-the-same-ids

Comment: Found nice explaination here: http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/

Comment: For range -5 to 256 memory location will be same for same value